# Rolling resistance, comfort or puncture proof?

Tags: tire, innertube, theoretical

**Edit**:
Adding another layer was useless, increased rolling resistance and XPS was squashed.
Changed then to slider cut from old narow tyre, but best experience was changing back tyre to 623x23c - worth one in tests, but 15-20min. less while commuting 20km, front change did not changed commute time then, but felt it rides easier and heard absolute no noise.

Worst problem is tyre wall mass - it is deformed every time while rolling and resistance probably depends most on periphery of contact area and width around periphery and width of side wall.

---

Thinking about new improvement - was not able to Google it.
After puncture last week though about something to prevent next and if possible improve rolling resistance or comfort.
So bought XPS Polystyrene in hobby market (5tons/m2 resistance, 3mm thickness) cut 2 layers from and place them between tire and tube.
What do you think, is it a good idea for better puncture proof, rolling resistance or comfort ?
After 40km today would tell, rolling resistance a bit higher, a bit more comfortable and hope better punture proof at least ;-)
From older experiments know, there is a big difference in resistance depending on thickness of tire (or tube too ?) and pressure.

**Edited:**
Ok, I experienced repeatedly punctures after 1st relatively small damage or small cut(?) in tire. But I am not sure, if it is a good idea to put something between - in case it will need to bend in that wider area, it will definitely increase resistance, but it looks like tire changed profile so not sure, also not sure what to use for it - example 5 tons/square meter is similar to 50kPa - deformation could be too big. I know there are puncture proof specials, but it is hard to get quickly. My subjective feeling after 40km is it increased comfort - similar like my gel seat also lock do not buzz so much as before on rough asfalt. So my question is - what do you think about this and would you suggest do the same with front tire or increase layers number of one or both ?
Btw found some comparison, best tire (tube-less) had only 7W resistance and worth in that test almost 30.
But suppose it should be very easy to compare by consumption of electric bike, same place & speed, but my is mechanical only.

For illustration including both tires photo - front original, back with 6mm XPS inside - looks straighter.[image][image]

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't well-suited to this kind of "Would this new product idea work?" questions. We're looking for concrete, objectively answered questions, not open-ended tell-me-what-you-think-s.

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm not sure what your asking to be honest, it looks like you had an issue with a puncture and have repaired it. What are you specifically asking?

Comment: *but it looks like tire changed profile* -- to me, it looks more like one tire (the rear) has significantly more treat wear than the other.

Comment: You can buy tire liner products to reduce puncture likelihood, so it could be a good idea. You’d have to test it. But if you’ve started getting repeated punctures in the rear tire, it’s because your rear tire is worn out down it’s centreline, see how much thicker the front tire tread is?

Comment: Do not use the bike during winter, so do not care about "worn" - there are road tires with no pattern and slimmer - but would tell thickness is the problem when you meet small piece of glass, etc. - it may or may not tuch tube at all.

Comment: I'd say, a serious puncture proof tire is very likely much better: They deliver the extra protector layers, but those layers are fused right into the tire, excluding any danger of mounting errors, friction between the layers, etc. And they work well: When I had my last puncture, it felt like way too early in the life of the tire. But when I checked, I found that I had already ridden the tire for over 7000km. My tires usually do much more than that before I find that one shard that's large enough to pierce their protectors.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask one instead of editing a previous one.

Comment: I would delete it as haters won, but it is not good practise and even after last edit it is still very similar to original question (if you ever read it), but way shorter. Or I can add: do not see any downgrade of comfort - maybe it is more even comfortable - probably because suspension works even or better(?) when tube pressure is high. Or I cannot change puncture proof layer (XPS->old tube->old tyre slider part), rim or tyre(/s) after asking ?? Did not get another puncture yet.

Comment: As far as I understand, the original was about tire liners and current version about why different tires have different rolling resistance.

Comment: I've rolled this back to version three of the question because I feel it is the closest to the original question you had in mind, with the additional experiences you had with a homemade tyre liner installed. If you have new questions, please ask them as new questions and make them as clear as possible. I see you've read the [tour]; there is a way this site works and if you keep changing the question, nobody's answers will make sense

Comment: If you know my mind better than me, why do not you ask your self ?? Anyway here are 2 very similar questions now, so one should be deleted, but I cannot change it nor delete(?). Is it a "closed" self QA site filled by moderators ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: We already have hundreds of almost similar questions about tire widths, derailleur compatibility and identifying BMX by serial number. One more does not do much harm.

Comment: @tom I admire your enthusiasm for projects - but SE isn't well suited for open ended questions that devolve into discussion.  Edits made by other users are intended to improve the quality while fleshing out details.  SE is a Q&A format, and substantially changing the question makes it confusing.  When I have a question to ask, sometimes I'll spend a couple days writing it up off-line before posting it.  Even then its easy to gloss over details by mistake.  The iterative editing process is to make the site better over all.  Your other option is to try the [chat] which is much less structured.

Comment: Please stop defacing your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried to read your post carefully. My understanding is that your question is:

> is it (a plastic barrier between the tube and tire) a good idea for better puncture proof, rolling resistance or comfort ?

The puncture proof part is such a good idea that it has been done.

As one example Rhinodillos has a line of tire liners that do what you describe (not an endorsement). Link to a review of tire liner types at [biketestreviews.com](https://biketestreviews.com/clean-motion-rhinodillas-flat-prevention-at-its-best/)
I have not seen any scientific testing that confirms tire liners will improve rolling resistance or comfort.

Just because this idea has been done don't be discouraged, keep having ideas and following up on them. Sometimes it seems like everything has been tried for bicycles but I believe there is still room for ideas.

Comment: XPS is useless - wanted to add next layer, but 1st 2 were constrict and shredded to small pieces like a paper... Replaced 'em with an old tube.